# conditionally closing div haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I need to achieve this

```
 <div class="row"> 
     <div class="col-sm-3"> 
      <div class="row">1</div>  
      <div class="row">2</div> 
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="row">3</div> 
      <div class="row">4</div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"> 
      <div class="row">5</div>  
      <div class="row">6</div> 
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="row">7</div> 
      <div class="row">8</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

if i % 2 == 0
then close existing .col-sm-3 and add a new one in HAML

I couldn't able to close div tag when the condition met,

I tried using

> yield_content

but no avail, any help is appreciated.

and I need to loop through this array

> facilities.each do |value|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about splitting array using [in_groups_of](https://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of)? E.g.:

```
.row
  - values.in_groups_of(2, false).each do |group|
    .col-sm-3
      - group.each do |value|
        .row= value
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this:

```
- [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]].each do |group|
  %div.col-sm-3
    %div= group[0]
    %div= group[1]
```

How I would create the array depends on what your actual data is and where it comes from.

Comment: sorry! its a dynamic array coming as mentioned above, just edited that for clarity